# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON on fileupload JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

When I'm uploading an image to my site I get an error `Error: parsererror SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input`

This is my function for uploading a file:

```
$('#form-upload').fileupload({
    dropZone: $('#inputAvatarProfile'), dataType: 'json',
    add: function (e, data) {
        error_message.html('');

        data.submit().success(function (result) {
            $('#csrf-uploadFile').val(result.csrf);

            if (result.success == 0) {
                error_message.html(result.error);
            } else {

                var crop_image = $('#jcrop_target');
                crop_image.attr('src', result.avatar_path);

                crop_image.Jcrop({
                    setSelect: [10, 10, 160, 150],
                    minSize:   [150, 150],
                    aspectRatio: 1,
                    bgColor: 'white',
                    bgOpacity: 0.5,

                    onChange:  function (coords) {
                        getCoordinateAvatar(coords.w, coords.h, coords.x, coords.y);
                        $('div.jcrop-holder').find('.jcrop-keymgr').css({opacity: 0});
                    },

                    onSelect:  function (coords) {
                        getCoordinateAvatar(coords.w, coords.h, coords.x, coords.y);
                        $('div.jcrop-holder').find('.jcrop-keymgr').css({opacity: 0});
                    }
                });

                avatar_default.val('');
                avatar_temp.val(1); 
                
                $('input[name="temp_avatar"]').val(result.temp_avatar);
            }
        });
        data.submit().fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.error('Error:', textStatus, errorThrown);
    })
    },
    progress: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('p.upload-progress').html('<?= Yii::t('advertiser_profile','load_progress'); ?> '+ progress + '%');
        if (progress == 100) {
            $('p.upload-progress').html('');
        }
    }
});
```

I don't know how console.log json object because I work with JS rarely. I've been trying to solve this problem for hours and didn't find answers online. Can somebody help?

Comment: Are you sure the server sends a JSON response?

Comment: You can view the response in the Network tab of Developer Tools.

Comment: @Barmar In request headers it says `Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01` and in response headers: `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Well there's your problem. It's returning HTML, not JSON. Why do you have `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: @Barmar I'm working with code of old project and dataType: 'json' worked there. Also if I make it dataType: 'html' - my response in data.submit().success will be null

Comment: If the server doesn't do any [content negotiation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation) (ie it ignores your `Accept` header), there's nothing you can do to force it to respond with JSON. If it returns HTML and you need data from that response, you'll need to parse it as such. jQuery can do this out of the box